# Error on displaying the graphical layout for an android app: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

I get this error when I switch from XML to GraphicalLayout in Eclipse. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AddPeople" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/AddPeopleList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddPeople_Name"
        android:hint="@string/AddPeople_ETHintName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddPeople_Number"
        android:hint="@string/AddPeople_ETHintNumber" 
        android:inputType="phone" />
</fragment>
```

I've checked through for obvious errors, but haven't spotted any. This is inflated in the normal way in an activity, but I think that problem is in the code. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Honestly, I never see the use of `<fragment>` tag like this (children tags inside `<fragment>`). As for your intent, do you want to create a  fragment? **Edit:** I hope it's just a typo that you missed `</LinearLayout>` at the end of the file.

Comment: ok, I'm learning at the moment. Wht would be the proper way to implement  frgment??? I do want to create a fragment, to have a list and then an editing panel

Comment: As the question is a bit broad, here are some tutorials to begin with `Fragment`: [the official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), and [Vogella's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html). Learn about the basic of fragment first, and when you have problem, then you can ask a new question. Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for the help!! I now know how to implement a fragment... I hope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create another app and past this cod in main xml file then go to graphical layout tab. Select the LinearLayout in Outline window and copy it an past your original app Outline window